# how to make a function to increase and decrease the tone of music with electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Has anyone ever made an app for music? I need to make a feature that lowers or raises the pitch of the song that's playing...

Which library to use to do this ilElectron? I still haven't decided which language to use. How do I capture an audio or video with audio and manage to increase or decrease the sound pitch? I want to do a KARAOKE show. In this program I will need to increase and decrease the pitch of the music. I'll do it with Eletron anyway.

Comment: Electron is a web browser window (chromium) so you have all the js builtin Audio API available.

Comment: WebAudio libraries?  Look at these https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/PitchShift.html,  https://github.com/cutterbl/SoundTouchJS

Comment: Do you have any tutorial on how to start doing step by step? I do not even know where to begin with...
My idea is to load the .mp4 video songs in a stored place in the system, and be able to decrease and increase the pitch of the music in that video.